# Django unable to distinguish between template directory when extending

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two apps, consisting of `adminApp` and `mobileApp`. Both have their own template directory and totally seperated. Unfortunately django keeps looking in the wrong directory when i eg. use `extend`, it looks into the first template directory according to the order in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'adminApp',
    'mobileApp',
    ...
)
```

My directory structure is:

```
adminApp/
    templates/
        base.html

mobileApp/
    templates/
        base.html
```

So basically what happens is that when i have a file such as `mobileApp/templates/pages/index.html` with a `{% extends "base.html" %}` it uses `adminApp/templates/base.html` instead of its own.

How can i avoid this and keep them separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apps don't follow the Django conventions for template directories. The app name should be repeated to avoid this issue:

```
adminApp/
    templates/
        adminApp/
            base.html

mobileApp/
    templates/
        mobileApp/
            base.html
```

You can then unambiguously specify which template you wish to extend:

```
{% extends "mobileApp/base.html" %}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that i could turn this `mobileApp` directory into a variable instead?

Comment: This structure gave me problems with the `registration` directory which overrides the default login system: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21242912/531203